# Where can I practice multivariate outlier detection?

Tags: outlier, kaggle

Can anyone provide me with a dataset, hopefully on Kaggle, where I can practice my skills in outlier analysis?
I have been studying this topic for quite a while, but I can't find a case study to apply my knowledge?

bonus points: if it had some categorical variables where I can practice various techniques for dealing with categorical variables and their correlation, it would be amazing. If not possible in the same dataset, it is ok also to guide me to two datasets

Answer (score 0):

You can download NASA's Turbofan Engine Degradation Simulation Dataset from [this link](https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/c/6/), which contains simulated sensor data from hundreds of turbines, with different failure modes under different operating conditions. In general, any sensor dataset will provide a good opportunity for outlier detection.

Comment: Do you have other recommendations?

Comment: Yes. Just search for outlier in the datasets section of kaggle (like this https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=outlier) and you will find multiple datasets featuring outlier detection.